# Creating a graph for data in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010, charts

I have two conditions (1-public, 2-Montessori) and a set of values based on the score of the children that is either a 0 or 1.

I need a histogram showing how many children got a 0 and how many got a 1 for each condition.

In total there would be 4 bars - condition 1 (0s and 1s); condition 2 (0s and 1s).

Does anyone have any idea how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Set up a 4 wide by 2 high range of cells, with "Public 0", "Public 1", "Montessori 0", "Montessori 1" across the top and then use the following formula beneath each one:

```
=COUNTIF(B3:B15,"=0")
```

Replace the B3:B15 with the column of 1's and 0's for the corresponding condition, and change the "=0" to "=1" for the 1 columns.

You should now be able to insert a simple bar-chart from the new set of cells.